# How to set a select query to a column of another select query in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have a query that I do not have a problem with.[you can see its result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ecmR.jpg)

```
SELECT
    FICHENO AS [Sifariş Nömrəsi],
    SHPAGNCOD AS [Maşın Nömrəsi],                     
    DATE_ AS Tarix, 
    ISNULL(CAST(T1.txtGirishSaati AS VARCHAR), '-') AS [Giriş Tarixi],
    CASE
       WHEN T1.txtGirishSaati IS NOT NULL
          THEN N'İcazə verilib'
          ELSE ' - '
    END [Giriş Statusu],
    ISNULL(CAST(T2.ChixishTarixi AS VARCHAR), '-') as [Çıxış Tarixi],
    CASE 
       WHEN T2.ChixishTarixi IS NOT NULL
          THEN N'İcazə verilib'
          ELSE ' - '
    END [Çıxış Statusu]
FROM  
    TGR3.dbo.LG_999_01_ORFICHE AS Logo
LEFT JOIN
    EBATEST.dbo.E_GirishFormu_Form as T1 ON Logo.LOGICALREF = T1.SifarisNoCombo
LEFT JOIN
    EBATEST.dbo.E_Chixish_Form as T2 ON Logo.LOGICALREF = T2.Sifarish
WHERE  
    Logo.TRCODE IN (1, 2) 
ORDER BY 
    T1.txtTarix DESC
```

But I want to make a column which is coming from this select:

```
SELECT
    o.FIRSTNAME + o.LASTNAME as 'Girişi Təsdiq Edən' 
FROM
    FLOWREQUESTS f 
JOIN
    OSUSERS o ON f.USERID =o.ID
WHERE
    PROCESS = 'GirishFormu' AND FOLLOWSTATUS = 5 
ORDER BY 
    PROCESSID DESC
```

So I want a column named 'Girisi Tesdiq eden' in the first query which is coming from the second query

Thanks in advance

Comment: but whats the relation between both queries? how is osuser/flowrequest connected with the first query?

Comment: OSUSER is a table where all users are gathered. Followrequest is a table where you approve an event. So my second query is also ok. I want a result of second query to be displayed in the first query, column name 'Girisi Tesdiq eden'

Comment: so second query shows who has approved the event..

Comment: Just join them all in a proper way. Add example data and expected result to your question to help others to help you.

Comment: In select list columns are returned either 'from' table or 'joined' table. Also in 'select', all tables having the relations with each other. So, your 1st query is perfect and your 2nd query is perfect too. But you have to use your 2nd query in the 1st query, for doing this you will have to join the both query based on their relation. So, define the relation to your question.

Answer (score 0):

A good tip for new users is to never post images as a result set, people in this community hate it.
We prefer beautifully formatted text instead.
Also, we love good verifiable datasets, queries, and examples like the below.

```
create table TableA(Id int not null, ValueA varchar(50) not null)
create table TableB(Id int not null, IdA int not null, ValueB varchar(50) not null)
create table TableC(Id int not null, IdB int not null, ValueC varchar(50) not null)

create table TableX(Id int not null, ValueX varchar(50) not null)
create table TableY(Id int not null, IdX int not null, ValueY varchar(50) not null)
GO

insert into TableA values
(1,'value of A1')
insert into TableB values
(1,1,'value of B1'),(2,1,'value of B2')
insert into TableC values
(1,1,'value of C1B1'),(2,2,'value of C2B2'),(3,2,'value of C3B2')

insert into TableX values
(1,'value of ')
insert into TableY values
(1,1,'A1'),(2,1,'C3B2')
GO

select a.ValueA, b.ValueB, c.ValueC, subquery.[join Field]
from dbo.TableA a
left join dbo.TableB b on b.IdA = a.Id
left join dbo.TableC c on c.IdB = b.Id
left join
(
  select x.ValueX+y.ValueY as [join Field]
  from dbo.TableX x
  join dbo.TableY y on y.IdX = x.Id
) as subquery on subquery.[join Field] = c.ValueC
GO
```

> ```
> ValueA      ValueB      ValueC        join Field
> ----------- ----------- ------------- -------------
> value of A1 value of B1 value of C1B1 NULL
> value of A1 value of B2 value of C2B2 NULL
> value of A1 value of B2 value of C3B2 value of C3B2
>
> (3 linhas afetadas)
> ```

Finally, this is an English language Q&A site, and while I find the British language, not the prettiest one I stick to it in my examples because most people here can understand only it.

I hope this was a useful answer.